# How do I selectively append "only options" or "optgroups with child options" based on the structure of the input array?

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble figuring out an algorithm for a function called "fillSelect" that iterates through an array and selectively appends either "only Option" elements, or "an Optgroup with children Options" to a parent Select element, based on how the input array is structured.

For example, if the input array is "selSiteVisDays", all items within the array become Options to the parent Select. If the input array is "selState", then the array items with "--" become an Optgroup and the other array items without "--" become the child of the above Optgroup.

I'm trying to accomplish this with only vanilla Javascript, no JQuery please.

```js
    const dataFrame = {
        "selSiteVisDays": [
            ["D00", "D00"],
            ["D03", "D03"],
            ["D07", "D07"]
        ],
        "selState": [
            ["--", "States"],
            ["AL", "Alabama"],
            ["AK", "Alaska"],
            ["AZ", "Arizona"],
            ["--", "Territories"],
            ["AS", "American Samoa"],
            ["GU", "Guam"],
            ["MP", "Northern Mariana Islands"],
            ["--", "Armed Forces"],
            ["AA", "Armed Forces Americas"],
            ["AP", "Armed Forces Pacific"],
            ["AE", "Armed Forces Others"]
        ]    
    };
    function fillSelect(classname, dataset) {
        const qryNodeList = document.querySelectorAll(`.${classname}`);
        for (let i = 0; i < qryNodeList.length; i++) {
            const eleOption = document.createElement("option");
            qryNodeList[i].appendChild(eleOption)
            for (let j = 0; j < dataset.length; j++) {
                const eleOption = document.createElement("option");
                const eleOptGroup = document.createElement("optgroup")
                if (dataset[j][0] === "--") {
                    eleOptGroup.label = dataset[j][1];
                    qryNodeList[i].appendChild(eleOptGroup);
                } else {
                    eleOption.value = dataset[j][0];
                    eleOption.textContent = dataset[j][1];
                    qryNodeList[i].appendChild(eleOption);
                };
            };
        };
    };
    fillSelect("visits-opt", dataFrame.selSiteVisDays);
    fillSelect("state-opt", dataFrame.selState);
```

```html
<select class="visits-opt"></select>
<select class="state-opt"></select>
```

Comment: The HTML part of the code is missing.

Comment: Are you open to changing the structure of your arrays? I would rather reflect the parent child relationship in the array itself, rather than use a delimiter

Comment: @Kinglish: I'm open to the restructuring of the input array, as long as it's minor.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping for something more compact, but here is one way of going about it. The benefit here is better readability of the data structure, easier traversal of the sub-option groups

```js
const dataFrame = {
  "selSiteVisDays": [
    ["D00", "D00"],
    ["D03", "D03"],
    ["D07", "D07"]
  ],
  "selState": [{
      'States': [
        ["AL", "Alabama"],
        ["AK", "Alaska"],
        ["AZ", "Arizona"]
      ]
    },
    {
      "Territories": [
        ["AS", "American Samoa"],
        ["GU", "Guam"],
        ["MP", "Northern Mariana Islands"]
      ]
    },
    {
      "Armed Forces": [
        ["AA", "Armed Forces Americas"],
        ["AP", "Armed Forces Pacific"],
        ["AE", "Armed Forces Others"]
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function fillSelect(classname, dataset) {
  let eleOption, eleOptGroup
  const qryNodeList = document.querySelectorAll(`.${classname}`);
  for (let i = 0; i < qryNodeList.length; i++) {
    // eleOption = document.createElement("option");
    //  qryNodeList[i].appendChild(eleOption)
    for (let j = 0; j < dataset.length; j++) {
      if (Array.isArray(dataset[j])) {
        // normal option
        eleOption = document.createElement("option");
        eleOption.value = dataset[j][0];
        eleOption.textContent = dataset[j][1];
        qryNodeList[i].appendChild(eleOption);
      } else {
        eleOptGroup = document.createElement("optgroup")
        for (let x in dataset[j]) {
          eleOptGroup.label = x;
          qryNodeList[i].appendChild(eleOptGroup);
          dataset[j][x].forEach(items => {
            eleOption = document.createElement("option");
            eleOption.value = items[0];
            eleOption.textContent = items[1];
            eleOptGroup.appendChild(eleOption);
          })
        }
        console.log(dataset[j]);
        qryNodeList[i].appendChild(eleOptGroup);
      }
    };
  };
};
fillSelect("visits-opt", dataFrame.selSiteVisDays);
fillSelect("state-opt", dataFrame.selState);
```

```html
<select class="visits-opt"></select>
<select class="state-opt"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is as below, with explanatory comments in the code itself:

```js
// original data Object:
const dataFrame = {
  "selSiteVisDays": [
    ["D00", "D00"],
    ["D03", "D03"],
    ["D07", "D07"]
  ],
  "selState": [
    ["--", "States"],
    ["AL", "Alabama"],
    ["AK", "Alaska"],
    ["AZ", "Arizona"],
    ["--", "Territories"],
    ["AS", "American Samoa"],
    ["GU", "Guam"],
    ["MP", "Northern Mariana Islands"],
    ["--", "Armed Forces"],
    ["AA", "Armed Forces Americas"],
    ["AP", "Armed Forces Pacific"],
    ["AE", "Armed Forces Others"]
  ]
};

// a named function, declared as a constant and written as an Arrow function,
// passing in the Object:
const fillSelect = (obj) => {

  // here we get an Array of the Object's keys, and cache those in the variable:
  let origins = Object.keys(obj);

  // here we iterate over those 'origins'
  origins.forEach(
    // passing the 'key' into the function body:
    (key) => {
      // caching the data:
      let data = obj[key],
        // finding the <select> element(s), using the added 'data-origin' custom-
        // attribute as the identifier:
        selectEl = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-origin="${key}"`),
        // creating an optgroup element, and an option element:
        optGroup = document.createElement('optgroup'),
        option = document.createElement('option');
      // iterating over the returned elements (in the event your document has
      // multiple <select> elements to which the same data might be added, which
      // is why I chose not to use an 'id'):
      selectEl.forEach(
        // for the current <select> element:
        (select) => {
          // we iterate over the data-array:
          data.forEach(
            // using destructuring assignment to declare the first array-element
            // as 'val' and the second as 'text':
            ([val, text]) => {
              // caching the check to see if the 'val' is exactly equal to '--':
              let test = val === '--',
                // creating a clone of the relevant element-type:
                clone = (test === true ? optGroup : option).cloneNode();
              // if the test is exactly equal to true:
              if (test === true) {
                // we set the label of the <optgroup> to be equal to the
                // 'text' variable:
                clone.label = text;
                // otherwise:
              } else {
                // we set the value, and text, of the <option> element:
                clone.value = val;
                clone.text = text;
              }
              // we find the last <optgroup> element in the <select>:
              let lastOptGroup = select.querySelector('optgroup:last-of-type');
              // if it exists, and so lastOptGroup is truthy (not-null):
              if (lastOptGroup) {
                // we append the clone to that last <optgroup>:
                lastOptGroup.append(clone);
              } else {
                // otherwise, if such an element doesn't exist, we
                // append the clone to the <select>:
                select.append(clone);
              }
            });
        });
    })
}

// calling the function: 
fillSelect(dataFrame);
```

```html
<!-- I added a custom data-* attribute to these elements
     in order to explicitly link them to the data that
     is intended to be appended to them; because you may
     wish to have multiple elements with the same content
     I chose to use a non-unique attribute, though if you
     can guarantee to only need to add data a single unique
     element, an `id` could certainly be used if you'd prefer
     or, indeed, any other attribute such as a class-name:  -->
<select class="visits-opt" data-origin="selSiteVisDays"></select>
<select class="state-opt" data-origin="selState"></select>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jd7a9hw6/1/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll/)
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll/)
- [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
- [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).
- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).